# Roblox key press not registering

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to call a function upon the user pressing the G key, however the key press itself isn't registering. I've used the print() function here in order to make 100% sure that it's not an issue with the function I'm calling.

The code I'm using is running in a LocalScript under StarterPlayer>StarterCharacterScripts

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
game:service'UserInputService'.InputBegan:connect(function(inputObject,gameProcessedEvent))
    if (inputObject.KeyCode=='G') then
        print("Key pressed!")
end)
```

The output in this case should be "Key pressed!", but nothing comes up in the output tab.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a function called `service` as used in

```
game:service'UserInputService'.InputBegan:connect(function(inputObject,gameProcessedEvent))
    if (inputObject.KeyCode=='G') then
        print("Key pressed!")
end)
```

Services are usually acquired by `GetService`.

Try

```
game:GetService('UserInputService').InputBegan:connect(function(inputObject,gameProcessedEvent))
        if (inputObject.KeyCode=='G') then
            print("Key pressed!")
    end)
```